# Anylogic- Splitting agents based on how many are in a conveyor

Tags: java, sorting, anylogic

How to split a conveyor based on how many agents are in one conveyor.
In this project I wanted to split agents so that only five agents would be on the top conveyor at any time. The others would be diverted away to the lower conveyor. (New Users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to split agents based on how many agents are on one of the conveyors you could use the selectOutput block. Simply set the condition to `topConveyor.size()<5` (assuming topConveyor is the conveyor block).